# How can I import WebAssembly rust to NextJS?

Tags: next.js, webassembly

Im using nextjs, I'm using an:

```
import { greet } from "backend";
```

This is the `package.json` dependencies:

```
"dependencies": { "backend": "file:../backend/pkg", "next": "11.1.2", "react": "17.0.2", "react-dom": "17.0.2", "webpack": "^5.52.0" },
```

This is my config on `nextjs.config.js`:

```
module.exports = { 
reactStrictMode: true,
experiments: { asyncWebAssembly: true, buildHttp: true, executeModule: true, layers: true, lazyCompilation: true, outputModule: true, syncWebAssembly: true, topLevelAwait: true, },
}
```

And this is my error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0) The module seem to be a WebAssembly module, but module is not flagged as WebAssembly module for webpack. BREAKING CHANGE: Since webpack 5 WebAssembly is not enabled by default and flagged as experimental feature. You need to enable one of the WebAssembly experiments via 'experiments.asyncWebAssembly: true' (based on async modules) or 'experiments.syncWebAssembly: true' (like webpack 4, deprecated). For files that transpile to WebAssembly, make sure to set the module type in the 'module.rules' section of the config (e. g. 'type: "webassembly/async"'). (Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem, if yes can you please share it with me? Right now I have the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

You need to edit the `next.config.js`

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config

Here is are the contents of my `next.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack: function (config, options) {
        config.experiments = { asyncWebAssembly: true };
        return config;
    }
}
```